# setBrightness when app enter Background

Tags: ios, screen, brightness

Is it possible to set the UIScreen Brightness when app will/did enter background?
I want to Change the brightness when the Home Button or is Push Notification from another app was clicked.

Answer (score 0):

you can change screen brightness by using this line

`[[UIScreen mainScreen] setBrightness:floatValue];`

Comment: I know, but at - (void)applicationDidEnterBackground:(UIApplication *)application
{
    [UIScreen mainScreen].brightness = 1.0;
}

it does not work

Comment: maybe because when current application enters in background, another application enters foreGround and sets the brightness to another value.